# Inno setup executes [UninstallRun] during installation

Tags: installation, inno-setup

Inno Setup 5.5.4(u)

Code:

```
[UninstallRun]
Filename: "{code:vJoyUnInstaller}";  Parameters: "/LOG /silent " ; StatusMsg: "Uninstalling vJoy device"; Flags: waituntilterminated
```

The function vJoyUnInstaller is called during installation. Debug tells me that it is called from the  [UninstallRun] section. Is it a bug or I just smoked something.

Answer (score 0):

The [UninstallRun] section is optional as well, and specifies any number of programs to execute as the first step of uninstallation. Both sections share an identical syntax, except where otherwise noted below.

Programs are executed in the order they appear in the script. By default, when processing a [Run]/[UninstallRun] entry, Setup/Uninstall will wait until the program has terminated before proceeding to the next one, unless the nowait, shellexec, or waituntilidle flags are used.

Note that by default, if a program executed in the [Run] section queues files to be replaced on the next reboot (by calling MoveFileEx or by modifying wininit.ini), Setup will detect this and prompt the user to restart the computer at the end of installation. If you don't want this, set the RestartIfNeededByRun directive to no.
[Inno-Setup-Documentation](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=runsection)

Comment: The problem here was that the `{code}` function was called at installation time (which one would not expect from the script code function in the `[UninstallRun]` section). It happens because the setup is evaluating `Filename` parameter for the uninstall log and so it executes the function.

Comment: @TLama Yep. That was the problem. Thank you