# Inno setup executes [UninstallRun] during installation followup

Tags: inno-setup

This question:

[Inno setup executes [UninstallRun] during installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23919656/inno-setup-executes-uninstallrun-during-installation)

E.g. Code:

```
[UninstallRun]
Filename: "{sys}\OfflineSvc.exe"; Parameters: "-uninstall"; WorkingDir: "{sys}"; Flags: skipifdoesntexist 32bit; StatusMsg: "Offline Processing service is being uninstalled. Please wait..."; BeforeInstall: SimpleStopService('Offline_Service', True, False); Flags: waituntilterminated
```

doesn't have a clear solution. It SEEMS to indicate the cause but provides no obvious solution (maybe I'm just dense).

Why does an UNINSTALLRUN item run during INSTALLATION?

If that is normal - how can you prevent it?

The INNO help says:

The [UninstallRun] section is optional as well, and specifies any number of programs to execute as the first step of **uninstallation**.

So one would expect that the UNINSTALLRUN section would only be executed when UnInstalling.

Sorry - I am new to posting on SO and it won't let me comment on the above question so I don't see any alternative to get more info except for posting a new question. If there is a better way for newbies please let me know how I SHOULD have done it.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include a script that demonstrates this behavior. It's impossible to determine whether or not there is an actual problem (or provide a solution) if you can't provide a way to replicate the issue. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for suggestions regarding how to do so.

Comment: Sorry. I asked for a *script*, not a single `[UninstallRun]` entry. Include a *sample script* that we can use to create a sample setup that will reproduce the problem. I could have copied your sample from the other post, but it doesn't reproduce the problem on it's own. See the minimal, **complete and verifiable** example link I provided before.

Comment: My INNO script is 550 lines long - is there a way to attach a file.

Comment: Our comments seem to have overlapped. :-) The Inno Setup samples folder has several examples of scripts that can be built (and the setup executed) as samples without actually installing files. Pick one, make your change to it to demonstrate the issue, and post it here.

Comment: Ok - probably going to be Monday before I can do that.

Comment: It appears that having a "code" method in the UnInstallRun section is causing the problem during installtion. This seems like a bug to me - since the section AND the help says it is for Uninstall ONLY - anything there should not be evaluated, executed or anything else unless it is uninstalling. So this seems like a bug to me. However, rather than waste my time on this, I am going to use InitializeUninstall to stop the service.

Comment: Thanks for the comments - I expect they will help others.

Comment: BTW - for the benefit of others, a BeforeInstall method is a "code" method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [UninstallRun] section does not actually run during the installation, but writes into the uninstaller log that is created during installation. You simply specify the [UninstallRun] section in the Setup script so that you can tell the uninstaller what to do in addition to removing whatever was installed e.g. you could use it to stop and remove a Service that you installed using sc.exe in the [Run] section during the installation.

In the referenced example, it is evaluating the {code} function to determine the hardcoded filename to add to the uninstaller log, as I believe the uninstaller cannot have a code query in to be evaluated at uninstall, only a hardcoded filename and path which is stored in the uninstall log.

Comment: If that was true - I wouldn't be asking this question. It DOES run during installation.

Comment: Please see additional information I just added. In the referenced example, the {code} function it is evaluated during installation to add the filename to the uninstall log, but it does not actually run during the installation.

Comment: I just noticed the "code" in the other example.
I added my item which does not have that.

Comment: You are calling a [Code] function by using `BeforeInstall: SimpleStopService(Offline_Service)` though. Assuming you are simply wanting to stop a Service prior to uninstalling, as it would appear is the case, you could simply use another line above this with `Filename: "{sys}\sc.exe"` and then in the `Parameter` add the `"stop Offline_Service"` to remove the need to use the `BeforeInstall` code function. You could also use `Filename: "{sys}\sc.exe"; Parameters: "delete Offline_Service"` to remove it.

Comment: @Toby, you are fine with your script (if the user won't move their Windows system directory path before uninstalling the app. since the `{sys}` constant is evaluated to the actual path when installing). The entry itself is executed at uninstallation time, just every parameter value of it must be determined (evaluated) at installation time, as Robert correctly answered. With that said you know what was the problem, a `{code}` function that was used for the `Filename` parameter executed at installation time.